# Make a class befriend a family of functions

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a class template

```
template <class Key, class T, class Hash, template <class> class Allocator>
class Table;
```

and a function template

```
template <class Key, class T, class DevHash, template <class> class DevAllocator, class HostHash, template <class> class HostAllocator>
void copyTableToHost(const Table<Key, T, DevHash, DevAllocator> &table, Table<Key, T, HostHash, HostAllocator> &hostTable);
```

Now I want to grant `copyTableToHost()` access to private members of both `table` and `hostTable`. In order to do that I made a friend declaration in `Table` class:

```
template <class DevHash, template <class> class DevAllocator, class HostHash, template <class> class HostAllocator>
friend void copyTableToHost<Key, T, DevHash, DevAllocator, HostHash, HostAllocator>(const Table<Key, T, DevHash, DevAllocator> &table, Table<Key, T, HostHash, HostAllocator> &hostTable);
```

My reasoning is that I don't need to specify `Key` and `T` as template parameters here since these are fixed for a given specialization. At the same time a given specialization needs to be friends with a whole class of functions which differ by the choice of `DevHash`, `DevAllocator`, `HostHash` and `HostAllocator` (I am not sure if template template parameters don't mess things up here ...).

The errors I get are of the form `member Table<Key, T, Hash, Allocator>::[member name] is inaccessible` which makes me believe that the friend declaration didn't work as intended.

Comment: The friend declaration needs to have the same number (and types) of template parameters, otherwise the compiler sees this as a different overload of the function.

Comment: I changed it into `template <class K, class U, class DevHash, template <class> class DevAllocator, class HostHash, template <class> class HostAllocator> friend[...]` but I am still getting the inaccessibility errors

Comment: Then it's time to post [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it as a free `friend` function template, one option could be to befriend all instances of it:

```cpp
template <class Key, class T, class Hash, template <class> class Allocator>
class Table {
    template <class K, class Ty, 
              class Hash1, template <class> class Allocator1,
              class Hash2, template <class> class Allocator2>
    friend void copyTableToHost(const Table<K, Ty, Hash1, Allocator1>& table,
                                      Table<K, Ty, Hash2, Allocator2>& hostTable);

    int x = 0; // private
};

template <class Key, class T,
          class Hash1, template <class> class Allocator1,
          class Hash2, template <class> class Allocator2>
void copyTableToHost(const Table<Key, T, Hash1, Allocator1>& table,
                           Table<Key, T, Hash2, Allocator2>& hostTable)
{
    hostTable.x = table.x; // now ok
}
```

Another option could be to instead use iterators and populate the table in a member function that takes iterators with the requirement they are dereferenced into a `std::pair<Key, T>` - or whatever class template you are using to package each `<Key, T>`. It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template <class Key, class T, class Hash, template <class> class Allocator>
class Table {
public:
    template<class It>
    requires std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type,
                            std::pair<Key, T>>
    void copyFrom(It first, It last) {
        // copy from `first` to `last`
    }
};
```